# Primes of the form $n^2-n+1$

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

Is it proved that there is only a finite number of prime numbers of the form $n^2-n+1$?

Comment: If $n=3m+2$ with $m\ge1, (n^2-n+1)(>3)$ is  divisible by $3$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not proved, not disproved. Every prime $p \equiv 1 \pmod 3$ can be written as $p = n^2 - nk + k^2 $ for integers $n,k;$ in some cases we may need $k <0.$ It is probably true that we can take $k=1$ infinitely many times and get a prime, meaning infinitely many values of $n$ as you asked, but noone is sure. Very similar question for $n^2 + 1,$ open question.

For the second question, the best thing that has actually been proved is that there are infinitely many primes $q$ that can be written in integers as $$ q = x^2 + y^4; $$ this is due to Iwaniec and Friedlander, and extremely difficult. Not only do we not know whether we can take $y=1,$ we do not know if we can take $y = z^2;$ that is, we do not know whether there are infinitely many primes of the form $x^2 + z^8.$

Comment: How to prove that every prime $p≡1\pmod3$ can be written as $p=n^2−nk+k^2$ for integers $n,k$? Thanks a lot

Comment: Euler proved that every prime $p \equiv 1 \pmod 3$ can be written in integers as $p = x^2 + 3 y^2.$ This is in many books, especially David Cox, Primes of the Form $x^2 + n y^2.$ Then take $$ n = x + y; \; \; \; k = 2 y. $$